# Text is not wrapping when max-width is set

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap

I am trying to make a horizontal scrolling container that contains a list of cards. Each card contains a set image and has details (title and description). The sizes of the cards vary depending the amount of text that is in the details. The max-width a card can grow to is 45em. Even when a card has a max-width, the text on the details side does not wrap and flows out of the card. I think my problem is because of the white-space: nowrap on the container div, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```css
.c-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 32em) {
  .c-card {
    max-width: 45em;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.container {
  overflow: x-scroll;
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container__listItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodt
Lorem ipsum dolo.

</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
       <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture"><source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Resetting white-space behavior on the details element resolves the problem.

```css
.c-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 32em) {
  .c-card {
    max-width: 45em;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.container {
  overflow: x-scroll;
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container__listItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.c-card__details {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodt Lorem ipsum dolo.

        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="container__listItem">
    <div class="c-card">
      <div class="c-card__image">
        <picture class="e-picture" id="js-picture">
          <source srcset="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/288x240" media="(max-width: 50em)">
          <img src="https://craftypixels.com/placeholder-image/356x240" alt="Alternate Text">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="c-card__details">
        <h3>Title Here</h3>
        <p>Helo hello heleljaeflfj; ajfdklsjakc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```